# Turn-based Multiplayer Board Game Storage

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have several ideas how to make a multiplayer turn-based board game (extremely simple), but I am looking for an effective and easy solution how to store session data for each game session.

Each session should take up to 1 hour, there should be 3 players and the game is simply about moving figures on a board while facing some actions and getting some gold after the game is finished.

1) My first idea was that I could make a socket server that communicate with the clients and checks if everything goes well (no cheating). For that I would probably have to use Java or other languages working on Linux server (that I have at my disposal).

2) I could just communicate with server by using HTTP and each second check out a new state stored at server (PHP script + MySQL storage).

3) Using some memcached solutions, though I have no idea how..

Do you have any experience with making game like this? It is extremely simple and I want to avoid any over-kill solutions. Also, I want to avoid paying for licences like Photon for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement such a game would be that players will take turn Asynchronously, in other words not all players will be online at the same time. In order to implement this, you can simply create a database table that keeps track of moves for each game. For example, one record would include gameID, playerID, turnID, moveDetails, etc. 
Your game client would notify the player when it's their turn and grab the records from the table and renders the updated game state.

If you are going for a Synchronous turn based, (all players online at the same time) then you should probably use Unity's networking and one of the players would act as the server and host the game.

Comment: There will be always 3 players playing against each other. They do not need to be online all the time. The question is: how can the player know if it's his or her turn? How can the client notify him or her?

Maybe checking this one record every second to find out, I am not sure.

Comment: is the client mobile, console, or PC?

Comment: It is mobile (Android, iOS).

Comment: If it's mobile then you can use Push notifications based on events.